# How to display a tooltip for each f:selectItem onMouseOver event

Tags: javascript, jsf, richfaces, tooltip, selectonemenu

I am trying to find a way to display a **tooltip** (or the html 'title' attribute) whenever I **mouseOver** an option element. I am using JSF's **t:selectOneMenu** and **f:selectItems**.

Values for the selectItems are passed as a variable (ArrayList) from my backing bean. My xhtml codes are found below:

```
<t:selectOneMenu id="mySelectOneMenu" value="#{backerBean.myForm.status}">
    <f:selectItems id="mySelectItems" value="#{backerBean.statusSelectItems}"/>
</t:selectOneMenu>
```

Values for the dropdown are Completed, Failed, and In Progress.
I want the tooltip say something about each status whenever hovered on.

I have tried using the **rich:tooltip** tag but could not get it to work to change dynamically. Can anyone please help me perform this. I am open to javascript or jquery methods. If it can be done using JSF tags and attributes, better!

Answer (score 0):

You will actually need javascript and css to tune this completely along with the richfaces tooltip. Richfaces 3.3.3 had a bug associated with tooltip.

[Here](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/) is an example of a jQuery plugin that should work with RichFaces.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26608934/how-to-use-jsfs-pass-through-attributes-with-fselectitems).
There's a `jQuery snippet` that adds `title` attribute to all `options` generated by `selectOneMenu/selectItems`.  Most browsers will render this as a tooltip.